# stop all movie animations on main timeline after x seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

Currently using the following code on the main timeline on its own frame to stop animations after 10 seconds:

```
setTimeout( function(){
stop();
},10000);
```

its not working, basically i have 3 movie clips on the main time line all looping continuously, but i want all of these movie clips to stop after 10 seconds.

currently using actionscript 2

bear in mind i also have an animation on the main time line as well that only plays on mouseover.

thanks

Comment: are those 3 movieclips nested in eachother ?

Comment: no, 3 individual movie clips placed on the main time line in their own layers

Comment: @Ben Yermak - The code i give you below works with the timeline, but also with any movie clip. Just replace `this` by the name of your movie clip container.

Comment: @BenYermak - Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

To stop all the MovieClips of your Main Timeline after a delay:

```
var timeline:MovieClip = this;
var delay:Number = 5000;

function toStop():Void {
    for (var c in timeline) {
        if (typeof(timeline[c]) == "movieclip") {
            timeline[c].stop();
        }
    }
}
setTimeout(toStop, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all 3 Movie clips a unique name and then change your code like this:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    yourFirstMC_name.stop();
    yourSecondMC_name.stop();
    yourThirdMC_name.stop();
},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopAllClips(clip) {
 for (var i in clip) {
  if(typeof clip[i]=="movieclip") {
   if(clip[i]!=clip) {
    clip[i].stop();
   }
  }
 }
};
stopAllClips(_level0);
```

This piece of code always works for me. It stops every movieclip in my flash animation, also the nested once!